How to Properly Configure Google Cloud CDN with Kubernetes?
How to Properly Configure Google Cloud CDN with Kubernetes Ingress?
How can I ensure that requests are first handled by Google Cloud CDN before reaching my Ingress?
Is there any misconfiguration in my current setup that might be causing this issue?
What are the best practices for setting up Google Cloud CDN with Kubernetes Ingress to achieve optimal caching and performance?
I think my configuration doesn't work because first handler of user query is ingress point is my load balancer and ingress in GKE not nearest GEO server from Google Cloud CDN.
Is this working like follow scheme:
user -> load balancer -> ingress -> cdn-service -> Google Cloud CDN -> frontend-app
I think it should be
user -> Google Cloud CDN -> load balancer -> ingress -> frontend-service -> frontend-app
What is correct configuration?
Here are my configurations:
Ingress Configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: cdn-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "cdn"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: cdn-cert
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /_next/static
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: cdn-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /static
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: cdn-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /cdn-test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-redirect-service
                port:
                  number: 80

Service Configuration
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: cdn-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"static-cdn-config"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80

BackendConfig Configuration
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: static-cdn-config
spec:
  cdn:
    enabled: true
    cachePolicy:
      includeHost: true
      includeProtocol: true
      includeQueryString: true
    cacheMode: FORCE_CACHE_ALL
    clientTtl: 31536000
    defaultTtl: 31536000
    maxTtl: 31536000
    negativeCaching: false
  customResponseHeaders:
    headers:
      - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com"


Your configuration sounds good. Be careful, it's not because the K8S objects are bound in a certain order that the request will follow the same path! Anyway, did you test your service access? Did you check the headers to validate the correct CDN serving?

Thanks for the answer. But if I ping my cdn domain from anywhere in Europe, North America, I always get one cdn ip where the different nearset GEO servers are?
How do I figure out which GEO servers are being used when I make a request?
To me it looks like the CDN is useless because all requests just go to my CDN ip.

Yes, all the requests goes to the CDN, if the content is there, it is served, else the request is forwarded to your deployment. About the geo server, I don't know. But, for me, I let the CDN do its job!
